# Get objects position in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array `players[]`

function that gets certain object from such array by looking up its `gameSocketId` value and returns that object

```
getUserInfo : function(user)
        {
            var userInfo = Game.players.filter(function(e) {
                return e.gameSocketId === user;
            }).pop();

            return userInfo;
        }
```

so I store it in a variable like `var user = getUserInfo(userId)` How can I than find out what is the position of `user` in array of `players[]` knowing all info about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
getUserInfo : function(user)
    {
        var userInfoIndex = Game.players.findIndex(function(e) {
            return e.gameSocketId === user;
        });

        return userInfoIndex;
    }
```

Note that `.findIndex`, while fully specified is not included in most JS engines by default yet - there is a polyfill on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
if (!Array.prototype.findIndex) {
  Array.prototype.findIndex = function(predicate) {
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.findIndex called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

This polyfill works on ES3 and ES5 browsers just fine :)

Of course, one can also use a normal `for` loop to do this which works all the way through ES1 - but then you don't get the fun syntax that conveys intent pretty clearly:

```
getUserInfo : function(user) {
    for(var i = 0; i < Game.players.length; i++){
        if(Game.players[i].gameSocketId === user) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

We don't always have to be clever :)
Of course, we can also always be inefficient and just call `.indexOf` after obtaining the item using your original method.

Answer (score 1):

The second param of `Array.filter` is the index for the current item. The below will still return you the userInfo that you originally specified plus you can use the index for whatever you want.

```
    getUserInfo : function(user)
    {
       var playerIndex;
        var userInfo = Game.players.filter(function(e, index) {
            if (e.gameSocketId === user) {
                playerIndex = index;
                return true;
            }
        }).pop();

        console.log(Game.players[playerIndex]) // <- the player that is also "user"

        return userInfo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `indexof()`

```
getUserInfo : function(user){
    var userInfo = Game.players.filter(function(e) {
        return e.gameSocketId === user;
    }).pop();

    return userInfo;
}

// and later
var user = getUserInfo(userId)
console.log(Game.players.indexOf(user));
```